# py2exe (version 0.11.1.0) not able to import wx files in dist folder

Tags: python, wxpython, importerror, py2exe

I am using Python 3.8 and wxpython 4.1.1. My python script is working fine in windows 10 64bit PC. However, when I am trying to convert the python script using py2exe, although it is able to produce the .exe file, the file is not working.  When I am trying to run the exe file, I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'wx'
```

My setup.py script is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import matplotlib
import fabio
import py2exe
import wx
setup_dict = dict(
options = {
        "py2exe":{
            "includes": ["fabio.HiPiCimage","fabio.pilatusimage","fabio.binaryimage",
                         
"fabio.pixiimage","fabio.mpaimage","fabio.adscimage","matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"],
            "packages":[],
        
        "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll", "w9xpopen.exe"],
        
    }
},

windows = [{'script': 'SAXS2D.py',
            "icon_resources": [(0, "SAXS2D_Logo.ico")]}]
)

setup(**setup_dict)
setup(**setup_dict)`
```

Is py2exe latest version not compatible to include the wxpython files in the dist folder?